# Grade Conversion in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have been working on this code for class, and everything I have done never seems to work! My work is in Visual Code Studio, and it does not bring up any sort of errors. I've looked it up and everything, and I just can't figure out why I can't get an output!

It is a grade conversion. By reading my code I guess you can figure out the parameters of the conversion. I just can't seem to figure out what is going on!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <pre>
    <body>
            
    <script>
    var grade=95;
    if ((grade >= 90) (and) (grade <= 100)) {
    document.write("A+ -- Exceptional!");
    } else if ((grade >= 80) (and) (grade <= 89)) {
     document.write("A -- Excellent!");
    } else if ((grade >= 70) (and) (grade <= 79)) {
    document.write("B -- Good!");
    } else if ((grade >= 60) (and) (grade <= 69)) {
    document.write("C -- Satisfactory");
    } else if ((grade >= 50) (and) (grade <= 59)) {
    document.write("D -- Barely Acceptable");
    } else if ((grade >= 0) (and) (grade <= 49)) {
    document.write("F -- Failure");
    } else   {
    document.write("An accepted grade was not implemented into the system.");
    }    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </pre>
    </html>
```

Comment: *"and it does not bring up any sort of errors"* - You're looking in the wrong place.  Check the console in your browser's debugging tools.  It's telling you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` is not a javascript operator.

Replace every `(and)` with `&&`

```js
var grade = 95;
if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
  document.write("A+ -- Exceptional!");
} else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
  document.write("A -- Excellent!");
} else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
  document.write("B -- Good!");
} else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
  document.write("C -- Satisfactory");
} else if (grade >= 50 && grade <= 59) {
  document.write("D -- Barely Acceptable");
} else if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 49) {
  document.write("F -- Failure");
} else {
  document.write("An accepted grade was not implemented into the system.");
}
```

Also you should not have `<pre>` tags outside of the `<body>`